# Extra spaces in files and getting error to upload them in SSIS

Tags: ssis

My client stores daily files into a folder and after that I use a SSIS package to import these tables into the SQL database.
Today I come across with an issue, the files that they sent have spaces here:
[image]

The SSIS  can not upload the files because of this space and in the SSIS package they put these  dots.
[image]

Does anyone know if it is possible to solve this automatically or I need to inform them that they need to re-upload the files without the spaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can work with this...

Script component:

```
Row.ID_Auto = Row.ID_Auto.Trim().Trim('"');
```

You might want to consider adding a new int column as well.

```
Row.ID_IntConversion = int.Parse(Row.ID_Auto.Trim().Trim('"'));
```

First Trim cleans the white space, and second trim clears double quote.

I am pretty sure you can figure something out with a derived column as well.

Comment: How I can add this into the SSIS package?

Comment: script component is a normal transformation in your data flow.